# Javascript object from string property and values

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to create a property based on string values.

I have a Json object, which used to fill the UI (select box).

```
"Conf" :{
    "Color":[
        {
            "Value":"BLUE"
        },
        {
            "Value":"GOLD"
        }   
    ],
    "Size":[
        {
            "Value":"12"
        },
        {
            "Value":"11"
        }
    ],
}
```

Based on the selection, I need to add it to an object (`Item.Conf` below).
`addSel` provides the selection type (`Color, Size` etc), and the value (`BLUE, 11` etc).
How can I add the selection as shown below.
So if the choice is `Color : BLUE`, I need to add it as  `Item.Conf[0].Color.Value = "BLUE"`
Is it possible?

```
Item = {
    Conf: [],
    addSel: function(type, val){ //for example type="Size", val = "11"

        //.... need to selection to Conf 
        // add a member "Size" from type string
        //set its value as val
        console.log(Conf[0].Size.Value) //=> 11
    }
}
```

In essence is it possible to make an object like

```
"Size":{
    "Value": 11
}
```

from strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear for what exactly you're trying to do, but perhaps you just need to know about using the `[variable]` syntax to address a property name using a string.

Example:

```
var x = {};
var propName = "Value";
x[propName] = 11;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
var x = {};
x.Value = 11;
```

But, the first form allows the property name to be a string in a variable that is not known at the time you write the code whereas the second form can only be used when the property name is known ahead of time.